# Eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix with a zero diagonal block

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a square matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n_1\times n_1}$, and a matrix $C\in\mathbb R^{n_1\times n_2}$. If they are concatenated into $B$ such that
\begin{equation}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & C \\
C^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I want to know the relation between the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A, B, and C.
Can the eigenvectors of B be derived from the eigenvectors of A and singular vectors of C?

P.S.: I know the trace of A and B are equal so the sum of their eigenvalues must be the same.

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are interlaced

Comment: @Exodd Thanks. I'm interested in the eigenvectors mostly.